# How to use a switch statement to narrow down a type using conditional types?

Tags: typescript

I have a 'Food' object that can be of multiple types depending on the value of the 'category' prop. The object comes from a json, so it is impossible to know the type before.

I'm trying to use a switch statement on the category prop in order to cast the Food object to the right type

```
export type Category = 'fruit' | 'grain' | 'meat'

interface Food<IngredientCategory extends Category> {
  name: string;
  category: IngredientCategory
  [key: string]: string;
}

interface Fruit extends Food<'fruit'> {
  color: string;
}

interface Grain extends Food<'grain'>{
  size: string;
}

interface Meat extends Food<'meat'> {
  temperature: string
}

type FoodFromCategory<IngredientCategory extends Category> = IngredientCategory extends 'fruit' ? Fruit : IngredientCategory extends 'grain' ? Grain : Meat;

const castFood = <IngredientCategory extends Category>(category: IngredientCategory, food: Food<any>):
   Food<IngredientCategory> | undefined => {
  switch (category) {
    case "fruit":
      return food as Fruit
    case "grain":
      return food as Grain
    case "meat":
      return food as Meat
  }
  return undefined
};
```

This creates errors on the lines with the return:

> TS2322: Type 'Fruit' is not assignable to type 'Food'.   Types of property 'category' are incompatible.     Type '"fruit"' is not assignable to type 'IngredientCategory'.       '"fruit"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'IngredientCategory', but 'IngredientCategory' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Category'.

Why doesn't the switch statement narrow down the "IngredientCategory" generic param? Is there another way I could do this?

[TS-Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKApgHgDg9gTgFwAQIJ5TEgwgQwWAc3lSQF4kByAMzgFcBLBCpAH0oLh3oDtm2KAtmDwVQoHvjhUcAY0wAxGDAAmAHgCS3DmGX0w3BLnxE4JSPm7KAztjyFiAPiQBvUEiTccQgFxIrCOB4CAG43JBk7E1RfTW1dfUNI4jCAbQBrMGi-AKCAXV9-QK1QkABfMRAJMClZBTpGJHN9ayRFFVVqeqYnVxB3GRgAG3gCnOLQcpBxA2rpOSQAcU4eRogLFra1Cg4uXgde9yt6AC8wUaKQiYqqmvmAWWFkJssbTY6hER6w-AEMTgRaHAztkLlcpiA0BhWkplPI4DABEZ7KYNFogfEDEioqt1jYsY4yEhYui9JikqYcc0bJ0GEwkAB+VpdJAxNE6UmJYzESkvdjLXgMxb8llIB54EqgAbcfzhHD+TaE1FxDn4inPFqq1AOAAUES5plZyoSmoANEgqDDfG8cNwtQBKbxhaHtYns43krWsJC0SxgKg8HRkL59PwAd0YMgAFkhdR67S4nbKrJgAEQ0Wkpx0h9zuIEAuDcc0wpBypm0xMRZNIFM7HiZxO5sD5wsWlQlmxLXYVuWpj4IevZnN5wEt4ulsUIMKTRvN72+-3cHQTEpAA)

Comment: Because `Fruit` is not a subtype of `Food<IngredientCategory>` and so you can't assign

Comment: What you want to do is a upper cast. This will not work. Return of the base interface "Food" will work. Then later use "category" to distinguish between them.

Comment: Do you mean to use `FoodFromCategory` somewhere?  Because you're currently not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not currently possible in TypeScript.  The [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) which narrows the type of `category` does not act to narrow the *type parameter* `IngredientCategory`, and so there is no way for the compiler to deduce that `Fruit` is assignable to `FoodFromCategory<IngredientCategory>` even if `category === "fruit"`.

The canonical issue asking for some solution here is probably [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912), and there are some specific feature  suggestions which might allow this if implemented, such as [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014).

---

But for now, the compiler just cannot do this by itself, and if you want this to compile you will need to do something like a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that it can treat (for example) `Fruit` as `FoodFromCategory<IngredientCategory>`:

```
const castFood = <IngredientCategory extends Category>(
  category: IngredientCategory, food: Food<any>
): FoodFromCategory<IngredientCategory> | undefined => {
  switch (category) {
    case "fruit":
      return food as Fruit as FoodFromCategory<IngredientCategory>
    case "grain":
      return food as Grain as FoodFromCategory<IngredientCategory>
    case "meat":
      return food as Meat as FoodFromCategory<IngredientCategory>
  }
  return undefined
};
```

That works and suppresses the errors.  But do note that this is you taking the responsibility for verifying type safety away from the compiler, and that you should be careful that you're doing it correctly.

---

Please note that, at runtime, the switch statement is doing nothing useful anyway.  JavaScript doesn't know about `Fruit` or `FoodFromCategory<IngredientCategory>`; all that will be emitted to JavaScript as `return food` for each case.  And if you're going to `return food` no matter what `category` is, you might as well write `castFood` this way instead:

```
const castFood = <IngredientCategory extends Category>(
  category: IngredientCategory, food: Food<any>
) => food as FoodFromCategory<IngredientCategory>;
```

which completely eliminates the `switch` statement.  It also eliminates `undefined`, since there's no valid way to call `castFood()` if `category` is not in `IngredientCategory`.

So that's the answer to the question as asked.  Stepping back, I'm a little concerned that you're trying to do "cast"ing here at all; the `category` parameter is not used at runtime at all, so it's only to help the compiler determine what type `food` is supposed to be.  But in that case you would probably be better off using `Fruit | Grain | Meat` as a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) with the common `category` property and then test that property instead of passing it in as a separate parameter.

But without seeing how or why you plan to call `castFood()` I wouldn't presume to venture in that direction (but maybe it looks like [this code](https://tsplay.dev/WYYvQW)).  Instead, I'll just reiterate that narrowing generic type parameters via control flow is not currently possible, and that you will need to use type assertions or some other type-loosening technique to get this to compile.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKApgHgDg9gTgFwAQIJ5TEgwgQwWAc3lSQF4kByAMzgFcBLBCpAH0oLh3oDtm2KAtmDwVQoHvjhUcAY0wAxGDAAmAHgCS3DmGX0w3BLnxE4JSPm7KAztjyFiAPiQBvUEiTccQgFxIrCOB4CAG43JBk7E1RfTW1dfUNI4jCAbQBrMGi-AKCAXV9-QK1QkABfMRAJMClZBTpGJHN9ayRFFVVqeqYnVxB3GRgAG3gCnOLQcpBxA2rpOSQAcU4eRogLFra1Cg4uXh6wq3oALzBRopCJiqqa+YBZYWQmyxtNjqERfb6UMAEMTgRaHBTtlzpcpiA0BhWkplPI4DABEZ7KYNFogfEDEioqt1jYsY4yGFYui9JikqYcc0bJ0GEwkAB+VpdJAxNE6UmJYzESnPdjLXgMxb8llIe54EqgAbcfzhHD+TYAeW4mHIqLiHPxFKeLU1qAcAAoIlzTKz1QldQAaJBUGG+V44bh6gCU3jCmzhCN1apJ5vJetYSFoljAVB4OjIn3cVgA7owZAALJCGv1OlxhfpyzAAIhotKzrq+7ncQIBcG41phSDlTNpVZeMI9iL93vZvuNevTsqs2Z2PHzneLYFL5ZtKjrQt24-d8Kb7ZbGM5yI7ha72feCH7K8Hw4rY+rYuQ1ennubxNbZPbDjCk23gPLQeUIbDygmEpAUplEXlldVZ4Xup5HU-QNMIjSXU0fQvJcrVHZQ7RhVQHWXVNSCcWCpwbGcvT-DVgLfIA)

Comment: Thanks you. What if instead of the castFood function, I want a function that returns a specific property of a Food object depending on its category? The params of that function would need to be generic as well as the return value (since it would change depending on the IngredientCategory). Is there a way to use the switch statement without using type assertion?

Comment: Without a [mcve] I can't be sure, but generics and switch statements don't usually work without type assertions; you can sometimes refactor to avoid this, but again, I'd need to see a concrete example I can play with to make any concrete suggestion.  (And if the issue diverges from the original question, then the best way to get an answer is a new question post instead of in comments.)

Comment: This seems to be possible now. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/76096184/578522

Comment: You could always have used unions instead of generics, but then the return type of the function will itself be a union and will not change depending on the input.  If you want the output type to depend on the input then unions won't give it to you.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible via unions ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMLCggNig3gKGWQGtQATALmQCIENsJqBuQ5KOM4AVwGcqQuAWwBG0FgF98%20UJFiIUAZQCOXOFDytSISjR4q1jFkR7AyEADIQQAczAALfkNFQJUsAE8ADortxvyAF40ehxkAB9kZVV1FnwAejjkAFoUhC4wFKT8GC4QBDBgAHsQZGsIMABBdTgACh5fbyoFBogASmQCYwB3YDAEO2Q6loA6LTJ2zqJkBDgeFFoQxgpWKbZyrigSgFk4e2GABQBJZAAqZHq-CGH2Tl5Ts4AmIymE1bf3ogA9AH4V6dn5npoks-kR1GANiULt5hiYzJYbPZ7sgnn9Xu8fqxJOIgA)):

```
interface Circle {
  kind: "circle";
  radius: number;
}

interface Square {
  kind: "square";
  sideLength: number;
}

type Shape = Circle | Square;

function getArea(shape: Shape) {
  switch (shape.kind) {
    case "circle":
      return Math.PI * shape.radius ** 2;
      //               ^? shape: Circle
    case "square":
      return shape.sideLength ** 2;
      //     ^? shape: Square
  }
}
```

Comment: If the return type of the function is supposed to depend on the input type then you can't only use unions, you need something like a generic function, and then you run into the issue where control flow analysis doesn't narrow type parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
switch (category) {
  case "fruit":
    food = food as Fruit
    return food
  case "grain":
    food = food as Grain
    return food
  case "meat":
    food = food as Meat
    return food
}
```