# Type narrowing for the return type of a function with switch

Tags: typescript

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIBGcUAXMgORwXIA+lhFANPkXAF7kgCuAtodFwBfXLhjcQCMMHQhkAcwhgM6AGpwANtwgAeVgGlkEAB6QQAEwDOyANYQAnuhhpMLAHwAKO-fL6AlOQqANr6ALo4rAiylmDIMehQEObqWigAvMga6AiaAMpgCXCKAHSKYACSkLxeDn4A3KyWAO7AYAgAFsg19n4RBAQ5ligARMRQw6Ss-cjAzh7xicma2sgAhGkZVDQAZNtxBYspK+ubjL1409Ng7VDoTcgAKvYADhAAolC3UB7DAKogNhAdzkY2G9Sm-REl2QiTA3CgcgWSSOEDqBAA9OjkGAXihgNYtnQGBQIYMRsR2BMIQNorFniQhksNMgMvSoENyuB5gdkct0htkDwNMyAPzIYYAOTgEuGyHISKZ2nB0NmXXxUolHjZjJSfnO1P611u9yerw+Xx+-0BwLYlL8Bqhl1h8Lk2t5GjRyEx2NxM2sPH4gmm5gg8G4GjAk2hRruyHNCQ8AAMrUCmiBE8rkCIRLgoiAYsgAG7kQn0CiMFkKJQqFEecskCjgvMF7hcPgCKCVso1vl1imNupAA)

The following code

```
interface Foo {
  bar: 'a' | 'b',
  baz: number
}

function getFooValue<
  K extends keyof Foo,
>(key: K): Foo[K] {
  const storedValue = localStorage.getItem(key);
  switch (key) {
    case "bar":
      if (storedValue !== 'a' && storedValue !== 'b') {
        throw TypeError("Unknown bar");
      }
      return storedValue;  // type is 'a' | 'b'
    case "baz":
      const parsedVal = parseInt(storedValue === null ? "NaN" : storedValue);
      if (isNaN(parsedVal)) {
        throw TypeError("Unknown baz")
      }
      return parsedVal;  // type is number
    default:
      throw Error(`Unknown`);
  }
}

const v: 'a' | 'b' = getFooValue('bar');
const u: number = getFooValue('baz');
```

generates error:

```
    Type '"a" | "b"' is not assignable to type 'Foo[K]'.
      Type '"a"' is not assignable to type 'Foo[K]'.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Foo[K]'.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

How should I make the switch statement narrow the return type? Assume that the passed-in `key` is always a literal string so the compiler can deduct.

This is different from [How to use a switch statement to narrow down a type using conditional types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68474835/how-to-use-a-switch-statement-to-narrow-down-a-type-using-conditional-types) as this question does not involve conditional types.

Comment: Does it *have* to be a `switch` statement? The function body can be implemented as a single line: `return foo[key];` Having a `switch` seems to be overcomplicating it. At most you might need this [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIBGcUAXMgM5hSgDmANPkXAF7kgCuAtodLgL65cMDiARhg6EMloQwGdADU4AGw4QAPEwDSyCAA9IIACYVkAawgBPdDDSZGAPgAUMTOQX0L18toCUHpgA2toAujhMwHbOllbIoMhu6H5MBFByHFDSSUGxoQDcQgRgABZQ6ADuyACiUOVQzgAGAKog5iCVII1+hfxAA) but also not with the example you have here.

Comment: @VLAZ Sorry for the confusion, I've updated the example to express my point.

Comment: You can't do this with `switch` or any case-based control flow, at least not currently. See [ms/TS#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) for the relevant feature request. Instead for now if you want generics you can refactor to an indexing operation, although it is kind of weird, see [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wOKJdw). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, the answer would address the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently (as of TypeScript 5.3) [generic types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) don't play nicely together in TypeScript.  If you use a `switch`/`case` or `if`/`else` statement to check a value of a generic type, this might result in narrowing the type of that value, but it has no effect on the generic type parameter itself.   In your case, `switch (key) { case "bar":` will narrow `key` from `K` to `K & "bar"`, but `K` doesn't get re-[constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `"bar"` in any way.  And thus the [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `Foo[K]` type cannot be seen to be assignable from a value of type `Foo["bar"]`, and the compiler complains.

There are various open feature requests in GitHub asking for an improvement; the most applicable one to your example code is [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014).  It looks like there has been some recent work on implementing this at [microsoft/TypeScript#56941](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/56941), so maybe someday soon your code will just work as-is. But until and unless that happens, you need to refactor if you care about compiler-verified type safety.

---

One way to refactor to get an generic indexed access *type* is to use a generic indexed access *value*.  That is, to get a `Foo[K]`, you index into an object of type `Foo` with a key of type `K`. This might seem implausible, but you can actually rephrase your `switch`/`case` code to have this form:

```
function getFooValue<
  K extends keyof Foo,
>(key: K): Foo[K] {
  const storedValue = localStorage.getItem(key);
  const foo: Foo = {
    get bar() {
      if (storedValue !== 'a' && storedValue !== 'b') {
        throw TypeError("Unknown bar");
      }
      return storedValue;  // type is 'a' | 'b'
    },
    get baz() {
      const parsedVal = parseInt(storedValue === null ? "NaN" : storedValue);
      if (isNaN(parsedVal)) {
        throw TypeError("Unknown baz")
      }
      return parsedVal;  // type is number
    }
  }
  return foo[key];
}
```

Inside the function the value `foo` is of type `Foo`.  Its properties are implemented as [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), meaning that they will only run if the relevant property is accessed.  Meaning `foo.bar` runs the `bar`-specific code, and `foo.baz` runs the `baz`-specific code.  And returning `foo[key]` is equivalent to switching on `key`.  But now the compiler can verify that `foo[key]` is of type `Foo[K]`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIBGcUAXMgORwXIA+lhFANPkXAF7kgCuAtodFwBfXLhjcQCMMHQhkAcwhgM6AGpwANtwgAeVgGlkEAB6QQAEwDOyANYQAnuhhpMLAHwAKO-fL6AlOQqANr6ALo4rAiylmDIMehQEObqWigAvMga6AiaAMpgCXCKAHSKYACSkLxeDn4A3JHRsTCYgZjIGXgEBGVsUB5+Ed3dwM4e8YnJmtrIAIRpGVQ0AGTLcQWTKTPzi4yDXcPdYAAWUOgA7sgAKvYADhAAolBn-QBEAKogNiAXcsRQr3qrGGIkOyESYG4UDkEySWwgdQIAHokcgwHcUMBrEs6AwKMDkEIWMNesR2AMhocoiAYshbiRLHDNB06QyIOVwOMNkzUh0FsgeBoNMgAPzIV4AOTgEteyHIsKmqSBYNGyA8WKlEo89KgjMVfn2BOGJzOlxu9yeLw8Hy+P3Ofw4gKNhOdEKhch1epSiOQKLRGOQWIFfAEUAJoJdBDd0OQLXQQW8oQaIlw1NpADdyDj6BRGCyyip4R5cyQKEC07FuFwQ9B80pC9MIMWyWW6kA)

Answer (score 1):

This is a [limitation of TypeScript's control flow analysis](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+control+flow+analysis+switch+sort%3Areactions-%2B1-desc+). You can use a single [function overload signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) to work around it:

```ts
// Before:

function getFooValue<K extends keyof Foo>(key: K): Foo[K] {
  // implementation…
}
```

```ts
// After:

function getFooValue<K extends keyof Foo>(key: K): Foo[K]; // <- Overload signature
function getFooValue<K extends keyof Foo>(key: K): Foo[keyof Foo] { // <- Implementation signature
  // implementation…
}
```

The overload signature is unchanged, and the implementation signature uses a return type which represents a union of all return types in the overload signature.

The diagnostic errors will no longer appear, and TypeScript will correctly map the return type:

```ts
const v = getFooValue("bar");
//    ^? const v: "a" | "b"

const u = getFooValue("baz");
//    ^? const u: number
```

[Code in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#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)

Comment: It looks like this completely disables type checking of the returned value?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78010478/type-narrowing-for-the-return-type-of-a-function-with-switch/78010591?noredirect=1#comment137528579_78010591) @xuhdev Yes, the return types are checked according to the annotated return type in the implementation signature. If you'd like to constrain the allowed return types, you can annotate a union of all values in `Foo` — I've updated the answer to show that, and here's an example of the constraint at work: https://tsplay.dev/WKXVDw